# How to add pagination for component front end (Joomla 2.5)

Tags: pagination, joomla2.5

I am new in joomla, i want to know how to add pagination to component for FRONT END,  from searching i found only pagination for back end only.

Answer (score 4):

So by default there is no pagination in front-end (at least from my knowledge).

It should work like in the backend.

Adding the pagination from the backend in the front-end is not the smoothest thing on earth but this is how it should work:

Your Model should extend JModelList

In the View (view.html.php) you call the Pagination

```
$this->pagination = $this->get('Pagination');
```

At the end in the component template (normally default.php) you will just add:

```
<?php echo $this->pagination->getListFooter(); ?>
```

For missing CSS classes add the missing files from the administrator side.

Let me know how it works.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more detail example?

Comment: You can check a component like com_banners to see how it works more detiled.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Valentin !
For more detail, in the View (view.html.php)

```
class ProjectViewMyProjects extends JViewLegacy{
protected $items;
protected $pagination;
public function display($tpl=null)
{
$this->items = $this->get('Items');
$this->pagination   = $this->get('Pagination'); 
.............................................
}
```

At the end in the component template (normally default.php) :

```
.................[foreach list of db query]...................[endforeach]
$this->pagination->getListFooter();
```