# Pagination in front end Module Joomla

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I've searching trough google for a way of adding pagination into a module, but i could only find information about adding it into components like here:

[How to add pagination for component front end (Joomla 2.5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425327/how-to-add-pagination-for-component-front-end-joomla-2-5)

Is it posible to implement this same principles to make a pagination for a module?, or a different approach is needed?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not the correct way of doing to try to implement pagination in a joomla module. Normally, only component are made to be able to use standard Joomla pagination, because it uses itself models and view controller...

The example we see on the link you propose is using pagination from the view controller (view.html.php), witch extend JViewLegacy (witch is an alias for JView). Pagination is natively supported by it.

I imagine you need to show many items pages on a module, but maybe reload the page for it is not the best option. You can perhaps try to load more items, and to use a JS script to do pagination (even a slider can do it nicely), or simply to add a link to the whole section of the associated component.

Comment: How could i make a JS script do pagination to the module?